# Why the variable is out of scope?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having some "weird" issue with my code. It's mostly in Spanish but I'm sure you will get.

```
$('#favoritos').live( 'pagecreate',function(event){
    var favoritos = false;
    var fav_bus = '';
    var fav_bici = '';
    if (!isLocalStorageAvailable()) // Si no hay Local Storage para qué queremos entrar aqui
        $.mobile.changePage('#errorFavoritos', { transition: "pop" });
    else{
        $.each(localStorage, function(index){
            var itemKey = localStorage.key(index);
            if (itemKey.indexOf('fav')){ // Si es un favorito
                var splitted = itemKey.split('-');
                var tipo = splitted[0];
                var numero = splitted[2];
                favs_locales[itemKey] = {
                    'numero' : numero,
                    'id' : itemKey
                };
                if (tipo == 'bus'){
                    favoritos = true;
                    fav_bus = '<div data-role="collapsible>' +
                                '<h3>Parada ' + numero+ '</h3>' +
                                    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="'+itemKey+'">';
                    pedirTiempos(numero).pipe(formatearTiempos).done(function(html){
                        fav_bus += html + '</ul></div>';
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        // Ya tenemos los datos formateados
        console.log(fav_bus);
        if (fav_bus != ''){
            $('#contentFavoritos').append(
                                '<h3 style="text-align: center;">Paradas de Bus</h3>' +
                                    '<div data-role="collapsible-set">' +
                                        fav_bus +
                                    '</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

The issue comes in this function:

```
pedirTiempos(numero).pipe(formatearTiempos).done(function (html) {
    fav_bus += html;
});
```

The `fav_bus` after the change (in the function) it's okay but `console.log(fav_bus)` just after the function and it's wrong. It's like it didn't changed within the function.

I've tried to return the `html` but what it ouputs is `[Object, object]` (as string).

Any hints?

EDIT:

I've tried to store it into a temporal DOM element and it's ok but I'm not being able to output that HTML (although it's there).

```
pedirTiempos(numero).pipe(formatearTiempos).done(function(html){
        fav_bus += html + '</ul></div>';
        $('#busTemp').html(fav_bus);
});

if ($('#busTemp').length > 0){
   console.log($('#busTemp').html());
```

And outputs nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, `done` looks like an asynchronous call. So the function you are passing to it is most likely getting run after `fav_bus += '</ul></div>`. This is why you don't see the change.

If you put a `console.log` inside the function you pass to `done` and another `console.log` just after the call to `done`, you'll probably see the outside `console.log` run first.

To fix this problem, any subsequent operations with `fav_bus` need to be done inside the anonymous function that you are passing to `done`.

Also, you cannot really return anything from an asynchronous function. This is why you need a callback, which will operate on the asynchronous result.

**EDIT**

Changing the code to `for..in` shouldn't really break anything unless you're explicitly using the loop index for something. You should be able to get it to work as-is with the following change:

```
if (tipo == 'bus') {
    favoritos = true;
    fav_bus = '<div data-role="collapsible>' + '<h3>Parada ' + numero + '</h3>' + '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="' + itemKey + '">';
    pedirTiempos(numero).pipe(formatearTiempos).done(function (html) {
        fav_bus += html + '</ul></div>';

        // Ya tenemos los datos formateados
        if (fav_bus != '') {
            $('#contentFavoritos').append('<h3 style="text-align: center;">Paradas de Bus</h3>' + '<div data-role="collapsible-set">' + fav_bus + '</div>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've changed my code enclosing it into an each instead a for which breaks the async part and tried to console.log and it's working but still no luck here. I have to perform some operations with different kinds and then, depending on what I get, output different things... Updating the code btw

Comment: The index is really needed as I'm looping through localStorage. I need to gather info and then, if I have them, show them and if not, show another thing.

Comment: Then you should be able to leave the code as-is (i.e., don't change it to a `for...in`).

Comment: But your code isn't totally what I need because the reason I'm using a loop is because I iterate over bus stops and bike stations. If you find bus stops, then add it some header, same with bikes and if you don't find anything, you need to inform the user. Iterating with that code will unnecesary code.

Comment: I guess it's not immediately obvious what you're trying to do. However, with the code I've given you, you should be able to solve the problem of `fav_bus` not being set to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `fav_bus` variable is local to the `.live` function and not visible to `.done`.

Moving the code out of the anonymous functions, this would be the same as:

```
function foo() {
   var a = 5;
   bar();
}

function bar() { // "a" is out of scope here.
   a += 5;
}
```

Comment: The example you've provided is not equivalent, and that's not what's happening here. The problem is that he is trying to use a variable that hasn't been properly initialized due to it being run in an asynchronous function. The anonymous function passed as an argument to `done` is in the same scope as the anonymous function passed to `live`. Since `fav_bus` is defined in the latter, it is visible to the function passed to `done` as well.