# issue with jQueryMobile/jQuery in a multi page site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with jQuery and jQueryMobile.

I have a site with 2 pages:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="main">
        <div data-role="header">
            header1
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <a id="1" href="#detail">link</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="page" id="detail">
        <div data-role="header">
            header2
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <div id="foo">content2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i press the link i save the id with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var test = 0;

                $('a').click(
                        function ()
                        {
                            test= $(this).attr('id');
                        }
                );        
            });
```

to this point, everything is fine. the problem is, when i want to read out the `var test` after i clicked the link, it is not saved anymore.

what can i do to prevent this?

i want to make something like this:

```
$('#foo').html(test);
```

Comment: What's thye problem?Your code seesm to work http://jsfiddle.net/eNcFB/ end test is saved

Comment: this code works, yes. but when i have the whole jQueryMobile site it dont works. on the jquerymobile site is something about dont using $(document).ready(). i should use pageInit() but i dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html

> **Important: Use `pageInit()`, not `$(document).ready()`**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as
>   the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

I would also suggest reading on [var Scope](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/) and [Closures](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/) in JavaScript

Related:

- [Why the variable is out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359028/why-the-variable-is-out-of-scope)

Answer (score 2):

Reading from your comment you need to use pageInit. Have you tried

```
$( '#main' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){

                var test = 0;

                $('a').click(
                        function ()
                        {
                            test= $(this).attr('id');
                        }
                );  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = 0;
$('#main').live("pageshow",function(event){ //or pageinit, or pagecreate
    $('a').click(
                    function ()
                    {
                        test= $(this).attr('id');
                    }
            );   
});
```